# Sending data from one page to another through javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I can simply send the data using window.location.href, first store the value to send from testing.html in script tag, variable say

`<script> 
var data = value_to_send
window.loaction.href="next.htm?data="+data
</script>`

this is sending through a get request
is there any way to send this through post means without showing in the url ?
and please tell the way how can i access that value in another page.
Thanks

Comment: why dont you use $.post(); method?

Comment: can u explain the use of $.post() by taking this example.

Comment: `$.post("next.htm", {"data" : data}, function(response){
/*do something with reponse eg: alert(response);*/
});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you tagged jquery, Here is a way of making an AJAX call with jquery:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "next.htm",
        type: "POST", // This could be POST, GET, PATCH, HEAD, etc..
        dataType: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify({"value1": "test"}),
        complete: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
```

The complete function, as http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ says:

> A function to be called when the request finishes (after success and error callbacks are executed). The function gets passed two arguments: The jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHTTPRequest) object and a string categorizing the status of the request ("success", "notmodified", "error", "timeout", "abort", or "parsererror"). As of jQuery 1.5, the complete setting can accept an array of functions. Each function will be called in turn. This is an Ajax Event.

This function is being executed whether the HTTP request is successful or not, so maybe you could handle the different HTTP status in the response, using:

```
if (data.status == 200) console.log('Request succeed');
```

Comment: what is this "complete" i had never use this, can u explain it

Comment: @lucky just edited the post with quite an explanation and also quoting the jquery doc.

Comment: i 'll be accessing that data in next.htm directly as an array with key value1 and its value test, or in any other way

Comment: You will receive the data in `application/json` type so you must be sure that you are receiving it that way, then you will have a var `value1` with value `test`